# Extract number between slashes

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

This is my setup:

```
var test = 
"http://tv.website.com/video/8086844/randomstring/".match(/^.+tv.website.com\/video\/(.*\d)/);
```

I want to extract the video id(8086844) and the regex does work, however when another digit is added after the "randomstring", it also matches the 8086844 + randomstring + other number.

What do I have to change in order to always get just the video id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex

```
/^.+tv.website.com\/video\/([\d]+)/
```

It will search every digit character after `...video\` word and then give all the concordant digits thereafter till any non-digit character comes

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `(.*\d)` part, it looks for a greedy string ends with a digit, instead you need a continues series of digits after `video/`, it can be done via `(\d+)`

change it to

```
var test  = "http://tv.website.com/video/8086844/randomstring/dd".match(/^.+tv.website.com\/video\/(\d+)/)[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var test = "http://tv.website.com/video/8086844/randomstring/8";
test = test.match(/^.+tv.website.com\/video\/(\d+)/);
console.log(test);
console.log(test[1]);
```

**Output**

```
[ 'http://tv.website.com/video/8086844',
  '8086844',
  index: 0,
  input: 'http://tv.website.com/video/8086844/randomstring/8' ]
8086844
```

You are almost there. We know that, its going to be only numbers. So instead of `.*\d` we are gathering only the digits and grouping them using parens.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest of all:

Use [substr](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) here

```
test.substr(28,7)
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jayeshjain24/M3TCP/)

To extract out the *id* from your string *test*:We use **substr(from,to)**